# VBA: Return multiple value in a single cell if the ID match

Tags: excel, vba

**Updated: I found the solution, that attached code will actually work. Still please put effort to read others comments as well**

I am using find function to match ID in Report Worksheet with the ID in Master worksheet and return the data corresponding to the ID in Report Worksheet if there is a match. The code is only returning the ID data which every comes first in the search range in Master worksheet. It does not go till the end of the search range in Master Worksheet.

How do I make the ID search till the end of ID Column in Master Worksheet? If the ID has multiple match then return the multiple corresponding data in single-cell with a new line.

Master and report worksheet example:
[image: Master and report worksheet example]

```
Sub Match_Control()

    Dim firstMatchRow As Long
    Dim wshM As Worksheet
    Dim wshR As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long ' To start Counter
    Dim LastRow As Long 'To check for last used row in ID columns
    Dim rngMatch As Range ' To define range where the match has to be found
    Dim xreturn As String 'To store the string for single cell

    Set wshM = Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Worksheet where the data is coming from,it is a source worksheet
    Set wshR = Worksheets("Sheet2") 'Worksheet where the information will be paste if the condition is satisfied
    LastRow = wshR.Range("A" & wshR.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'Check for the last row in column A in SRDS ID worksheet. It will check from bottom and which is the first used row
    For i = 2 To LastRow 'counter from i=2 to last used row
        Set rngMatch = wshM.Range("A:A").Find( _
            What:=wshR.Range("A" & i).Value, _
            LookAt:=xlPart) 'Range (J:J) is where the data will be looked in SRDS to Control worksheet, Find is what we are looking for from the SRDS ID and jump to next row with IngRow counter,
                            'xlPart is what it will be looking at, instead of xlWhole I have used xlpart.

        If Not rngMatch Is Nothing Then
            firstMatchRow = rngMatch.Row

            Do

                wshR.Range("B" & i).Value = xreturn & rngMatch.Offset(0, 1).Value
                Set rngMatch = wshM.Range("A:A").FindNext(rngMatch)
                xreturn = wshR.Range("B" & i).Value & ", "
            Loop Until firstMatchRow = rngMatch.Row

        Else
            wshR.Range("C" & i).Value = "NOT FOUND"

        End If 'When the condition is executed and finished,
        xreturn = Empty 'To clear the xreturn value for next do loop
    Next i 'Increase the counter by 1 and go to search function again
End Sub
```

Comment: Use [`Range.FindNext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.findnext) perhaps. There are examples here on SO to show you how to use it.

Comment: Using Range.Find is an overkill for this problem. It makes your code hard to understand. You could use loops and dictionaries for this.

Comment: is there any specific reason you unaccepted my answer after accepting it?  I am happy to revisit and edit my answer if you can tell me why it did not work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Edited to adapt to the updated question and written generically:

```
Option Explicit
Sub GroupByID()
    Dim dKey As Long
    Dim dItem As String
    Dim dict As Object
    Dim cell as Range
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    For Each cell In Sheet1.Range("A2:A" & Sheet1.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        dKey = cell.Value
        If Len(dKey)>0 Then
            If Not dict.Exists(dKey) Then 
                dict.Add dKey, cell.Offset(0,1).Value
            Else
                dict.Item(dKey) = dict.Item(dKey) & vbCr & cell.Offset(0,1).Value
            End If
        End If 
    Next
    Sheet2.Cells(2, 1).Resize(dict.Count) = Application.Transpose(dict.Keys)
    Sheet2.Cells(2, 2).Resize(dict.Count) = Application.Transpose(dict.Items)
End Sub
```

Answer to previous version of question:

When using`Find` on a single column, I store the row number from the first match in a variable before entering a `Do` loop that repeatedly calls `FindNext`.  `FindNext` doesn't remember where it has been and will happily  find cells it has already found and continue finding them until the heat death of the universe.   The infinite loop is avoided by comparing that variable to the row number of every subsequent match and then exiting the loop if they are equal.   Or put another way, the loop starts by trying to find the second match so the only way a row number can equal the first match is if the last match was found and the loop restarted.

It might look something like this...

```
    For lngRow = 2 To lngLastRow
         Set rngMatch = wshM.Range("A:A").Find( _
             What:=wshR.Range("D" & lngRow).Value, _
             LookAt:=xlPart)
         If Not rngMatch Is Nothing Then
             firstMatchRow = rngMatch.Row
             Do
                 wshR.Range("E" & rngMatch.Row).Value = rngMatch.Offset(0, 1).Value
                 Set rngMatch = wshM.Range("A:A").FindNext(wshR.Range("D" & lngRow).Val)
             Loop Until firstMatchRow = rngMatch.Row
         Else
             wshR.Range("F" & lngRow).Value = "NOT FOUND"
         End If
     Next lngRow
```

Some things to watch out for:

The new variable firstMatchRow is not declared.  It should be`Long`

I did not presume to know the importance of your `For` loop so I kept it intact; but it is unlikely that you wanted to to write all matches to the same cell. So I took the liberty of changing the ouput row.

`For` and `FindNext` don't always compliment each other very well. You may want to reconsider your looping strategy depending on your requirements.

This is one keystroke away from an infinite loop, consider adding `Do Events` as a precaution against a locked Excel session.

Look into `Application.ScreenUpdating`